# How to implement or extend product gallery widget

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, widgets

In template of module product-video. Widget **productGallery** called by `data-mage-init` attribute with `template` option pass through

```
<div id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHtmlId() ?>"
 class='gallery'
 data-mage-init='{"productGallery":{"template":"#<?php
 /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHtmlId() ?>-template"}}'
 data-images="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getImagesJson()) ?>"
 data-types="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(
     $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($block->getImageTypes())
 ) ?>"
> 
   CONTENT 
</div>
```

My question is how to implement in right way to creat simple multiple upload images. Do i really need `getImageTypes` like original code. I don't want use all image type